# Intel i915 driver not in any of the diplays

Tags: drivers, graphics

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. Everything was working fine until I booted up Ubuntu this morning and it froze at the purple screen, sometimes going to black screen then freezing there. I started it in recovery mode which worked, and it said to put in a nomodeset at the splash screen, so I did. I got in normal boot, but the screen resolution is messed up. The right edge of the screen is cut off and if I move the cursor to the right then it shows, but then the left edge is cut off. When I checked the additional drivers, it was completely empty, with nothing in it. In addition, the entire screen seems stretched out.

Running

```
lshw -c video
```

gives me this:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV635/M86 [Mobility Radeon HD 3650]
       vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:bfff0000-bfffffff memory:bff00000-bff1ffff   *-display
UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fc000000-fc3fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8)
```

running

```
lspci | grep -i vga
```

gives me this:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series
Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07) 01:00.0 VGA compatible
controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV635/M86 [Mobility
Radeon HD 3650]
```

and in system settings it says my driver is VESA: Intel(r)Cantiga Graphics

is there any way to fix the stretch and the edges being cut off, and to be able to boot in normal mode without the nomodeset?

Comment: Please i need help